# Как разделить 6 фотографий на две колнки?

Tags: html, css

Как разделить 6 фотографий на две колнки? Чтобы было вот так вот: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: grid or flex? загугли, там все понятно.

Comment: Используйте `grid`.

Comment: codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qBMjePR - это flex

Comment: codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bGxrGdB - это grid